# PySide: Using QAbstractListModel with QListView

Tags: python, pyside, qlistview, qabstracttablemodel

I have a litle problem with QAbstractListModel in python. I am trying to create my own model. The problem is that the view does not display lists of my values.

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
import PySide.QtCore
from PySide.QtGui import *
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

class ModelPoc(QAbstractListModel):
  m_items=[];
  def __init__(self,parent = None):
    QtCore.QAbstractListModel.__init__(self, parent)

  def initialize (self,mlist):
    self.m_items = mlist;

  def rowCount(self, parent = QModelIndex()):
    return len(self.m_items)

  def setData(self, index, value, role = Qt.EditRole):
    if role == Qt.EditRole:
     self.m_items[ index.row() ] = str(value.toString());
     self.dataChanged.emit(index, index);
     return True
    return False

  def data(self, index, role = Qt.DisplayRole):
    ret = "test";
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
      ret= str( self.m_items[index.row()] );
    print (ret);
    return  ret;

    def flags(self, index):
      return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow, ui_test.Ui_MainWindow):

  m_pocModel = poc_model.ModelPoc();

  def __init__(self,parent=None):
    super(Main,self).__init__(parent);
    self.ui = ui_test.Ui_MainWindow();
    self.ui.setupUi(self);
    self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.clickedMyButton);
    self.init();


  def init(self):
    self.ui.listView.setModel(self.m_pocModel);
    Main.m_pocModel.initialize(["test", "tes1t", "t3est", "t5est", "t3est"]);
    self.ui.listView.show();

  @Slot()
  def clickedMyButton(self):
    text = self.ui.lineEdit.text();
    self.ui.label.setText( text ); 

app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv);
test = Main();
test.show();
sys.exit(app.exec_());
```

After I run this script, I dont see anytithng in the listview.

Comment: There seems to be a copy/paste error: you haven't shown your model class.

Comment: Your code is far away from a _minimal_ example.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why the view does not display anything, is because the `data()` method of your model is returning incompatible values.

The [data](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractitemmodel.html#data) method has to return data for [many different roles](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum), and it does not make sense to return the same value for all of them. In particular, your implementation returns a string for the `SizeHintRole`, which will end up being interpreted as `QSize(0, 0)`. This because, internally, PySide has to convert the value to a `QVariant` before passing it to Qt. A [QVariant](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html) can represent many different data types, but conversion between types is not always possible - so for those cases, an invalidated default is returned instead.

Your `data` method implementation should look more like this:

```
    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            row = index.row()
            if 0 <= row < self.rowCount():
                return self.m_items[row]
```

(For unhandled roles, PySide will convert `None` to a null `QVariant`, as per the Qt documentation).